# Test if parameter to glob is actually a npm glob pattern or a simple flat file

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I'm looking for a method to determine if the object submitted to glob is actually a glob pattern or just a list of one or more flat files.

```
function tellMeIfGlob(p) {
   ...
}

tellMeIfGlob('file.txt') -> false
tellMeIfGlob(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']) -> false
tellMeIfGlob('*.js') -> true
tellMeIfGlob(['*.js', 'src/**/*.css']) -> true
```

Comment: Immediate question: why? Do you have a use case that you can describe where doing this is necessary or useful, and where you don't actually know your own glob input before passing it into glob?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In a complex gulp build environment I would like to identify explicit file definitions and check if they actually exist.

Comment: That gets us halfway there, but misses the point: *why* do you need to check if those files exist, instead of having the relevant section of the gulp build deal with checking for that?

Comment: Now I'm not I understand you. I have tasks in my gulp file that require that a given file exists and others that process a variable number of files. If the number of files to process is given gulp.src should also really process this predefined number. In practice this means that if gulp.src receives a list of "flat" files, would like to test if each file really exists.

Comment: Right, so why not just let glob do what it needs to? Glob will only return results it matched in the filesystem, so it *already* does the "does this file exist?" check for you. That's why I'm asking: why do *you* need to check this as well when the returned data by glob is real data on your disk? (So the workflow is "get pattern, run through glob, get data result, for each entry in data do what needs to be done". Nonexistent files or even patterns simply don't factor into that, and don't cause problems)

Comment: It's exactly the other way around. The fact that nonexistent files simply don't factor in is the problem I'm trying to solve. I do want to catch the cases where explicitly (not using a pattern) files are specified and throw an exception if they are missing.

Comment: without a concrete example it's hard to comment but it **really** feels like you're solving the wrong problem, or the right problem the wrong way. If there are patterns with files that don't exist, what generated those patterns and why were they allowed through? This question might not get to that solution in comments, though. The simplest shortcut is "check for wildcards. If no wildcards, this is literally a filename, or names"

Comment: Imagine a very large gulp file and someone adds a new file but just misspells it or a file is removed from the repository and is forgotten to be removed from the gulp file or the file is moved around (actually the most common case in real live) but the reference in the gulp file is not changed. This happens quite regularly and would just like to minimize those cases.

Comment: That... shows a really poor process. If someone can add actual individual files, those files shouldn't be things in their own right, they should be new file entries in directories that are already monitored by the gulp tasks. New files should not lead to "we need more patterns", so in this case it sounds very much like at the very least that "adding a new pattern" should be part of a pull request that gets a review before being merged in. With that said, check for wildcards. If no wildcards, the patterns are files.